# What is the underlying technology behind ServiceAsync interface?

Tags: gwt, client-server

I developed a web application (works properly) which registers a user to the system and allows user to upload a file to system via https. The client side code is totally developed by using GWT 2.4 and the back end is several servlets. Except the upload code, all the client-server communications are done via using `ServiceAsync` interface as it is the common practice in GWT. The upload code is based on a form which is communicating with the upload servlet directly.

This project is developed as a course work and my Professor is keen on knowing the underlying architecture of google web toolkit specificly focused on the client-server communication. His question was,

"How the client code knows the server's url so that all the communication is done?"

His question is legitimate for the `ServiceAsync` interface. I am calling a function on the server side which seems interesting to him and he wants to know the underlying process behind it.

For uploading, I just defined `uploadForm.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"upload");` where upload is the name of the upload servlet in web.xml.

I told him that the compiler generates Javascript code which contains all the web application code (whole system developed dynamically) and the url to the servlet is placed in that script file however the answer did not satisfy him. Please let me know the inner facts of the client-server communication with GWT.

Please give me some answers that can help my Professor to understand GWT's asynchronous client-to-server RPC communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying technology is [shown here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuidePlumbingDiagram) as a diagram. [Google says](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideServerSide) "GWT provides an RPC mechanism based on Java Servlets to provide access to server side resources. This mechanism includes generation of efficient client and server side code to serialize objects across the network using [deferred binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasics.html#DevGuideDeferredBinding)."

The client knows the URL to query because you would have annotated your service interface with a `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` tag. This associates the service with a default path relative to the module base URL. That URL is where Javascript sends your request.

There's a lot more to learn about GWT's RPC if you care to, and you can start picking it apart [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html).

Comment: That's what I forgot! I could have mentioned the @RemoteServiceRelativePath which would make things more clear. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in GWt how to bind RPC service to the specific url. 
First is an annotation @RemoteServiceRelativePath which is placed on synchronous interface. Using deferred binding rule GWT will discover this URL and will set it to the service instance automatically.

Second is casting instance of GWT-RPC async service to the ServiceDefTarget and setting an url manually.

But this answer alone will not satisfy your professor, because most likely he will want to know some other details, so I recommend you to learn how exactly GWT-RPC works.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the basic question of how the client knows the url of the server, it sounds as though the professor may be asking about the full url of the site (the domain name), and not just the sub-directories for the services as they are defined in @RemoteServiceRelativePath and the web.xml.

For this more fundamental aspect of the question, I think the "Same Origin Policy" (SOP) that browsers have for javascript security could be an important part of the answer. This is [explained](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?) in one of the GWT FAQs. The first thing that the browser is doing on the client side (after the HTTPS connection is established, which I think could be another important part of the answer) is reading the host html file, where the bootstrap nocache.js file is referenced. Once this file is loaded, the SOP is going to guarantee that all of the subsequent JS application files are coming from the same server as the bootstrap and the host html files. Once the application files are loaded, then everything is happening within that context, with specific internal url paths being defined for RPCs as already mentioned.